# Global variable assignment issue

Tags: python

I have a problem with assigning global variable names inside a function. Here's what the function looks like:

```
def nodegen(slabel, dlabel, sx, xy, dx, dy, num):
   for i in range(1, num + 1):
      label = slabel + (i - 1)*dlabel 
      global vars()["n" + str(label)]
      vars()["n" + str(label)] = Node(label, (sx + i*dx, sy + i*dy))
      vars()["n" + str(label)].info()
```

Actually, it's not important what the function does. What is important is that it generates a number num of objects. Every one of them is assigned a variable n1, n2, ..., nnum (the indices do not necessarily have this sequence, it depends on the dlabel variable, but that's not really important). I want to make these variables global, so I can use them outside the function. The problem is line 4 of the code, since it seems the global statement doesn't work with the vars()[] statement. Any ideas on how to solve this problem? I get an "invalid syntax" error message.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to find a better way to code, not fix this existing code. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: `vars()["n" + str(label)]` does not look like a valid global variable name

Answer (score 1):

You should treat `globals()` as a dictionary, like this:

```
def fun(name, value):
    globals()[name] = value
```

Once you execute this function it will add or update a global variable named `name` with value `value`, e.g. to add variable 'a1' with value 10 call `fun('a1', 10)`.

`vars()` without an argument acts the same as `locals()`. See http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#vars

Be warned however, that adding global variables like this is probably a bad idea. You should make it a method of a class and update the state of an instance of the class instead. Alternatively, you should be returning something or updating the structures passed in. Bugs with code like this are difficult to find and diagnose since the place where variables are modified isn't immediately obvious (as is the case when one observes the rules of [encapsulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_%28object-oriented_programming%29).

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I am aware this concept is not ideal, but it's only for the sake of experimenting with the code for now.

Answer (score 1):

Use your own `dict`, instead of abusing symbol tables. Also, your function tries to repeatedly overwrite that variable, I presume you want to build a list instead.

```
def nodegen(nodes, slabel, dlabel, sx, xy, dx, dy, num):
    label = slabel + (i - 1) * dlabel
    key   = 'n{0}'.format(label)

    nodes[key] = [
        Node(label, (sx + i * dx, sy + i * dy))
        for i in range(1, num + 1) # use xrange in Python 2
    ]

some_nodes = {}
nodegen(some_nodes, ...)
nodegen(some_nodes, ...)
```

Don't use globals, unless they're absolutely unavoidable, or actually provide a significant benefit.